# Oracle-sqldeveloper shortcuts. How to edit a cell and what are the most used. To reduce mouse manipulation

Tags: sql, oracle, keyboard-shortcuts, oracle-sqldeveloper, shortcut

I have not found a hot key to begin editing the selected cell. Only a combination of keys Ctrl+Space, that just toggles the selection, but does not do anything useful. Which of these hotkeys:
[image]

is most important and sufficient to reduce the frequency of their use of the mouse to a minimum. And perhaps there is a need to connect external modules for this purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hitting the spacebar on a cell will toggle to edit mode

there's no key sequence to activate the data editor - to get a calendar for dates for example though - need to log an accessibility bug for that

The most used shortcuts are probably around executing statements in the SQL Worksheet, ctrl+enter, F9, F5.

I have a few of [my favorites doc'd here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/11/keyboard-shortcuts-in-oracle-sql-developer/).

Comment: Thanks! And how could I disable preview when mouse over cell?

Comment: sorry @Artem.Borysov, don't believe you can disable that